# How to keep program from closing?

Tags: ruby

I'm using a Ruby interpreter to run the code I created(a simple guess a number 1-100 code), but every time you guess the number correctly or incorrectly after x number of times it automatically closes itself after it prints out "You Win!" or "You Lose!". Here's the code:

```
srand
random_number = rand 1..100
guesses = 10

while guesses > 0
  puts "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100."
  print "What number am I thinking of?"
  guess = gets.chomp.to_i
  guesses -= 1


  break if guess == random_number
  puts "Too high" if guess > random_number
  puts "Too low" if guess < random_number
end

if guess == random_number
  puts "You win!"
else
  puts "You lose, sorry!"
end
```

How can I keep it from shutting itself down, so the user can see the displayed message?

Comment: SO is Q-A. You've already received answer on original question. Please, if you have new question, click Ask Question button. If needed, add a reference to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not end with:

```
puts "Hit enter to exit."
gets
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new to ruby so this quick response was very helpful!